# What regular expression can I use to get the values of a place (string) and amount (integer) from a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to derive the place (string) and the amount (float) from a string using regex in PHP.

The target string would be formatted like this

> 7 Eleven Manly West 10.00

The place is a string of a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and hyphen characters.

The amount is in money format as so - **10.40** - **10** dollars and **40** cents. The amount can also be a negative, and doesn't retain a zero (**4.30** - **4** dollars and **30** cents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to use regex if you know it will always be formatted like this where the amount will be the last part.  You can do

```
$data = explode(" ",$inputstring);
$amount = array_pop($data);
$place = implode(" ",$data);
```

but if you really want a regex try something like

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)+)(-?[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]{2})
```

You can then get the place in the first back reference and the price in the 3rd

Comment: I like your answer better and it's probably faster than using regexp.

Answer (score 2):

If you can **guarantee** that there will always be a price at the end this will match your string:

```
preg_match(/^(.*)(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$/, $yourString, $matches);
```

and `$matches` will be

```
array(
  0 => '7 Eleven Manly West 10.00',
  1 => '7 Eleven Manly West ', 
  2 => '10.00'
)
```